# PHP help sorting array by another arrays? Unusual case

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I get data from a database, and save each parameter to a different array. In this case, I'm getting data about songs. I don't really know how to explain it, so here is an example:

```
    $restracks=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (tag1='$tag1' OR tag1='$tag2' OR tag1='$tag3' OR tag2='$tag1' OR tag2='$tag2' OR tag2='$tag3' OR tag3='$tag1' OR tag3='$tag2' OR tag3='$tag3') ORDER BY trackid DESC");;

    while ($rowtracks=mysql_fetch_array($restracks)) {     
        $trackid=$rowtracks['trackid'];
        $artistid[$trackid]=$rowtracks['uid'];
        $trackname[$trackid]=$rowtracks['trackname'];
        $artists[$trackid]=$rowtracks['artists'];
        $filename[$trackid]=$rowtracks['filename'];
        $dllink[$trackid]=$rowtracks['dllink'];

        $tracktag1[$trackid]=$rowtracks['tag1'];
        $tracktag2[$trackid]=$rowtracks['tag2'];
        $tracktag3[$trackid]=$rowtracks['tag3'];
    }
```

This is just a snippet of the code. Then, I count the tag matches of each track (least 1, max 3) with the user-prespecified tags like so:
                    //match calculator

```
        $match[$trackid]="0";

        if (($tag1==$tracktag1[$trackid]) || ($tag1==$tracktag2[$trackid]) || ($tag1==$tracktag3[$trackid]))    {
            $match[$trackid]=$match[$trackid]+1;
        }
        if (($tag2==$tracktag1[$trackid]) || ($tag2==$tracktag2[$trackid]) || ($tag2==$tracktag3[$trackid]))    {
            $match[$trackid]=$match[$trackid]+1;
        }
        if (($tag3==$tracktag1[$trackid]) || ($tag3==$tracktag2[$trackid]) || ($tag3==$tracktag3[$trackid]))    {
            $match[$trackid]=$match[$trackid]+1;
        }
```

And end it with
    $tracks[]=$trackid.
Then I use foreach ($tracks as $trackid) to display them and add play buttons etc.

However, I'd like to sort them by tag matches, so the tracks with most matches display first. I know this may be hard to understand and is quite messy, but if anyone does, please help :/
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will have two arrays, one containing the total matches for tracks and the other the traks themselves you can use `array_multisort()` to sort one array based on other array.

Something like this:

```
$tagCount = array(
    1234 => 1,
    3456 => 3,
    5566 => 2
);

$tracks = array(
    1234 => array('name' => 'Track1', ...),
    3456 => array('name' => 'Track2', ...),
    5566 => array('name' => 'Track3', ...),
);

array_multisort($tagCount, SORT_DESC, $tracks);
```

As a result of this in the `$tracks` array you will have the tracks in this order:

```
3456, 5566, 1234
```

Note that when two or more tracks will have the same value for the tag count they will be sorted based on the values in the second array, so it might be a good idea to provide a 'second level' sorting option if you need one, e.g. `array_multisort($tagCount, SORT_DESC, $trackNames, SORT_ASC, $tracks);`